# How to skin custom controls in JavaFX 2.2 without causing CSS warnings?

Tags: java, user-interface, custom-controls, javafx-2

Using Java 7 Update 6 with integrated JavaFX 2.2,
it appears that as soon as I define a custom `UserAgentStylesheet` for a `Control` and therein define a `-fx-skin`, JavaFX's `StyleHelper` complains about missing references to CSS "variables":

```
WARNING: com.sun.javafx.css.StyleHelper calculateValue Could not resolve '-fx-outer-border' while resolving lookups for '-fx-background-color' from rule '*.tab-pane *.tab-header-background' in stylesheet jar:file:/C:/Programme/Java/jdk1.7.0_06/jre/lib/jfxrt.jar!/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/caspian/caspian.bss
```

With a single custom component, there are about 40 warnings like the above.

I am probably missing something, as this is my first attempt at custom skinning, but I am not sure what it is.
Neither SO, nor the JavaFX-dev ML nor the FX documentation, not even the code from JFXtras pointed me to an obvious cause of this.

In case it matters, I am directly extending `Control` and implementing `Skin`, but the same happens if I e.g. extend `Button`, overwrite `getUserAgentStylesheet()` and have the CSS point to the default `ButtonSkin`.

Can you point me to my mistake or a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well yesterday, however not at every build. If you use JFXtra I found this post on the OTN Discussion Forums: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2430102

Comment: I found that thread as well, so I at least know what's happening.
However, I neither use JFXtras, nor is the new component shown in a ``PopUp`` window.  There are ``PopUp``s in the program, though.

Answer (score 0):

It's a known issue in JavaFX and you could use the following workaround to avoid these warnings:
Check if getScene() != null before adding nodes to the control
This fixed the problem for the JFXtras controls.

Comment: when I check for ``getScene() != null`` before adding my custom control to a container and register a listener on the control so it is added once the Scene is set, the control does not appear any longer.
I had a look at the JFXtras Labs and at your Ensemble, but I couldn't find the place where you do it.
Could you point me to it, or extend your answer a little so it becomes clearer where to take action?

Thanks.